# GridLayout will not show up on device, only in Android Studio

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am creating a very simple activity for my nephew to learn Android and, during design time, I can see the grid, but when I put it on my Samsung Note 4 (android 6.0.1) it's completely empty.

Here's a screenshot of the grid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z4rC.jpg

And this is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="j.ChoosePlayer">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        tools:columnCount="2"
        tools:rowOrderPreserved="false"
        tools:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pink_matte"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/netpetxml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="New File"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/contpetxml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Continue File"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/cloudxml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Send / Receive"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/magenta3button9"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/filexml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Files"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/graybutton9"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/testxml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bluebutton9"
            android:drawablePadding="-50sp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/configxml"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Preferences"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
            tools:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            tools:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
            android:onClick="onChameleon"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chameleon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
            android:onClick="onOctupus"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/octopus" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have this configured:

> minSdkVersion 23 targetSdkVersion 25

And not using the Support library, as this is going to be run on only my phone.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width on the buttons, it is coded to 0, change it to wrap content if the image sizes are similar or to fill parent with just a margin to 5dp, try not hard coding the gui with sizes because it might make problems.
Hope it solved Your problem.